# Endpoints returning BufferInputStream with strange value in Mulesoft Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have 3 separate APIs, A, B, and C. A and B are completely independent, whereas C queries A and B to compile data together. Each API is in its own project and running on its own port (8081, 8082, and 8083, respectively).

I am able to successfully hit A and B individually AND through C...sort of. When C hits one of these endpoints, the result comes back as a `glassfish.grizzlly.utils.BufferInputStream`.

I've dealt with this `BufferInputStream` type before by using a Transform Message Component. However, doing so here simply produces an error, saying that `payload.id` is of the wrong type (it should be an integer). When running this in debug mode, I can see that A has an Output Payload with id: Integer (it is of a custom type). However, upon moving back into C's flow, the payload is now the aforementioned `BufferInputStream` type, and I'm unable to directly access `payload.id`.

In short: How do I retrieve data in one project from another project?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

I used an Object to String transformer on the `BufferInputStream` to get a better look at the value. It appears to be in the format of a URL:

id=12345&name=nameValue&otherVal=%5B8499%5D...

I can `#[payload.split('&')]` at this point and get most of what I need, but then there's still the issue of things like the following:

```
summary=Words+with+plus+signs+in+the+middle
```

Again, I can work around this with things like `split`, but surely this is not what is intended.

Update 2:

I discovered the following warning:

```
[[test].api-httpListenerConfig.worker.01]
org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpResponseBuilder: 
Payload is a Map which will be used to generate an url encoded http body but
Contenty-Type specified is application/java; charset=windows-1252 and not
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I'm not entirely sure what to do with that info, though the Contenty-Type typo is interesting ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! In A and B, I needed to use an Object to Byte Array transformer before returning the value. This allows me to use a Byte Array to Object transformer in C and get the original value back.